# cordova: deviceready not firing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create login page where i am using ajax to validate the data. It is working fine if i use document ready but when i used `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` it is not firing the ajax.

Here is the code which i have at the moment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    //$('document').ready(function()
//{

    $("#login").on("submit", function(e) {      
    alert('test');
some ajax code goes here

});
};
</script>
```

This code is inside foot section. i have included cordava.js in head section.

Please advise what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Here is your Code
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#login").on("submit", function(e) {      
            alert('test');

        });
    };
});
```

Sometimes document needed to ready, like all required files downloaded to fire or attach a event handler.

Comment: why do i need to use document ready. Because i never seen document ready in cordova examples.